# How to fix unneeded Code Coverage?

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, test-setup

I have a testclass with the following structure:

```
@isTest
public class UnitTests {

    @testSetup
    static void setupTestData(){
        // insert some sObjects
    }

    @isTest
    static void firstUnitTest(){
        //the test itself
    }

    private static String getFirstTestPayload(){
        return 
            'this' + 
            'is a ' +
            'static string';
    }

}
```

*To add to that, there are about 20 unit tests, and two tests have one payload (a successfull test, and a failing test), so an additional 10 payloads.*

It currently shows that out of 1800 lines (the entire file), I need 83 lines covered.
I believe this is caused by the @testSetup function, and the payload functions, however I can't find out which lines actually need covering. I've also tried running another testclass which calls a payload function, to create some code coverage that way, but that doesn't add any coverage either.

How do I:
a) find out which lines are the ones needing coverage?
b) remove the unnecessary need for code coverage in this test class?

Comment: a) If you open your class in the Salesforce developer console, you'll be able to see the lines covered.

Comment: Are you complaining about the platform telling you your test classes themselves need coverage?

Comment: These situations are ideal for TestFactory classes that create your data. @testSetup isn't an ideal solution for all test class situations.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why do Methods marked `@TestSetup` in Classes marked `@IsTest` count against test coverage requirements?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139238/2995)

Comment: Martin, I cannot. Currently I am unable to get any lines covered, and therefore my code Coverage is 'None' and that will not show any code coverage (also in normal classes without any coverage).
Adrian, yes in a way (but not because of the @testSetup, but because of all of the payloads).
Crmprogdev, in testsetup I am inserting required custom settings. All of the setup for the unittest itself in this case is done in the unittest function itself.